How to open embed monaco editor instead of create a new model when use command+click to go to type definition? like click react module?
It seems that the embedded editor is only displayed when clicking on the react module, like this react definition: 
But I want to be able to open the embedded editor by clicking on other modules instead of create a new model in editor.
How can I do this?

I found a solution: just set definitionLinkOpensInPeek:true.
